# PHP Login works but then randomly gets kicked out asked to relogin

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication

I have a php login with two users. Everything seems to work fine but I am randomly getting booted and required to log back in. I My thoughts are that my session is timing out? Sometimes there are two people using the same login at the same time. Any thoughts

```
<?php //login code
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
        if ( $password == "pass" && $user == "user") {
             $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
             header('Location: index.php');
             exit;
    } else {

    if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
        if ( $password == "pass2" && $user == "user2") {
             $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
             header('Location: index2.php');
             exit;
 }
}                


?>
```

//  ===

```
<?php // approval code

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['phplogin'])
    || $_SESSION['phplogin'] !== true) {
    header('Location: login.php'); //Replace that if login.php is somewhere else
}

    <?php // index code
include('approve.php');
include('connect.php');

?>
```

Comment: If the session was timing out, you'd see a different session ID show up in the session cookie as a new one's created.

Comment: Marc B could you tell me where/how I could see the see the cookie id? New to backend development thanks.

Comment: Check your browser's cookie management section. On Firefox, you can use Firebug to view/manipulate cookies.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any output before the session_start or the include('approve.php'). E.g. if you have those spaces before opening your php tag, it will be too late to start the session.

Comment: @Nabab --- that is always a good warning, but could that result in an intermittent problem like this one?

Comment: @Smandoli - If it is really random, and not after a period of inactivity, I'd say it's more a problem of losing the session in the script than on the server.

Comment: I am still getting bumped off. It does seem to happen after a short time of inactivity. Used to Firebug to see the session id and that doesn't seem to change. Removed all the additional spaces before my start_session. Could it be two people are using the same password at the same time?

Comment: Also my files are located in a sub folder don't know if that would cause any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your code is a little buggy so ill help you get that sorted, if your doing hard coded credentials then it would be best to keep the user / pass in an array so you do not have to rewrite your code for each user.

create a file called `accounts.php` and paste the following snippet

```
<?php

return array(
     "username" => "password"
     /*.. More Below ..*/
);

?>
```

then your login code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['user']) || !empty($_POST['pass']))
{
    $users = require('accounts.php');

    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    //loop the accounts.
    foreach($users as $_username => $_password)
    {
        if(strcmp($user,$_username) === 0 && strcomp($pass,$_password) === 0)
        {
            //Valid Account
            $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

this should be sufficient,

the issues regarding the logout it may be due to inactivity for the expiration period, if a request has not come into the server from the client the session garbage collector will remove the session as it has expired.

you can rad more at the link below including how it works and how to change the values:

[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960)

if you wanted to set custom conditions for each member such as static profile data, routing information this requires you to increase the array by 1 dimension as well as a small restructure, so your accounts page would look like so:

```
<?php

return array(
     array(
         "username" => "the_username",
         "password" => "the_password",
         "after_login" => "home.html"
     )
     /* More Below */
);

?>
```

and your login code would then be slighty changed to fit accordingly.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['user']) || !empty($_POST['pass']))
{
    $accounts = require('accounts.php');

    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    //loop the accounts.
    foreach($accounts as $account)
    {
        if(strcmp($user,$account['username']) === 0 && strcomp($pass,$account['password']) === 0)
        {
            //Valid Account
            $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
            header('Location: ' . $account['after_login']);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

if your not sure what i mean by dimensions here's a quick example:

```
  $array[0][1][10]['username']
  /*     |  |  |       |
         |  |  |       |
         1  2  3       4    > dimension
  */
```

this allows the values of the 3rd dimension to always be bound to 2, and to then gets bound to 1

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks great. In my code had two users going to separate index pages based on login. How would I do that with an array? Thanks for your help.

Comment: see my update, it just requires a an increase of depth within the array to keep the users information together and some modifications to the login process.

Comment: One last time! I am getting this error... 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function strcomp() in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/49823/domains/domain.com/html/pm/login.php on line 14

Comment: my mistake, i have been working on other languages too much, omit the **o** so it becomes **strcmp**

Comment: Robert success. Login is working. fine what would you place in an approve script? I have something like this..... `<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.massivestudios.net'); 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['phplogin'])
    || $_SESSION['phplogin'] !== true) {
    header('Location: login.php'); //Replace that if login.php is somewhere else
}
?> `

Comment: why are you using `session_set_cookie_params`? and whewn your checking if a session exists you can just use the empty function which performs an isset as well as checking if a value exists! so `if(!empty($_SESSION['phplogin'])){/*all good*/}` would suffice

Comment: @RobertPitt it seems that if I use and empty session I doesn't require a login? It bypassed the login and takes me to the index page.

Comment: then just use an explicit `=== true` check, should suffice

Comment: Okay so I have tried all the options from above but am still getting the boot randomly and asked to log back in. I am sure it is something wrong with my approve script. The "if(!empty)" and "=== true" bypass my login and you can access private page content. Here is my current code which does work (but I am getting booted) `<?php     
    session_start();  
    if(!isset($_SESSION['phplogin'])){/*all good*/
    header('Location:login.php');  
    exit;  
    }   
?> `

Answer (score 2):

You could try the PHP functions for getting/setting the session id. You are also able to set the cookie params as you wish: `session_set_cookie_params(31536000, '/', 'your.cookiedomain');` (more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)